# AVRdude + Arduino leonardo: can't flash over bootloader, not in sync: resp=0x3f

Tags: avrdude

I would like to program an arduino leonardo board with atmega32u4 on win8.1 x64.
I have the latest AVRdude.
I installed the necessary drivers, after reset it can be enter programming mode, and I can program with **arduino studio**.
But now, the avrude gives this:

```
    C:\>avrdude -carduino -P COM5 -n -p m32u4 -b19200 -v

avrdude: Version 6.1-svn-20131205, compiled on Dec  5 2013 at 17:34:22
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "c:\GNU_GCC_ARM\bin\avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM5
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I tried also with 57600 baud.
Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the wrong bootloader protocol via -carduino. The Arduino bootloader is for boards using the Diecimila bootloader. The Leonardo uses the "AVR109" bootloader - named after the [Atmel Application Note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1644.pdf) which describes its protocol.

Try this command on for size:

```
avrdude -cavr109 -P COM5 -n -p m32u4 -b57600 -v
```

Don't forget to press the reset button (or open and close COM5 at 1200 baud) first to run the bootloader.